# jquery remove of prepended element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I want to have two functions. The first prepends an element `div` which contains some ajax data and a button which can fire the close function. The first function does everything I want it to, except I'm having trouble applyin the `onclick` attribute on the  which will fire the remove function when clicked.

But independent of this, I haven't been able to get the `remove function` to work.

If you can help me do this better I would be grateful.

```
function displayCrRef(refPid, refFs, pidOfReferringP) {

    $.get("crRefParaExtract.php", {
        pid: refPid,
        fs: refFs
    }, function(data) {

        $("#pwrap_" + pidOfReferringP).prepend("<div id='#crRef_" + refPid + "' style='float: left;  width: 350px; margin-right: 60px; padding: 10px; background-color: #E6EDE8'>" + "<a id='crossRefRemoveButton'>Return to normal text</a>" + data + "</div>");


    });
    var rmFxnParam = "'" + refPid + "'";
    $("#crossRefRemoveButton").attr("onclick", "removeCrossRef(" + rmFxnParam + ")");
    $("#" + pidOfReferringP).css({
        float: 'left',
        width: '425px'
    });
    $("#menu_" + pidOfReferringP).css({
        float: 'none',
        clear: 'both'
    });
   }


   function removeCrossRef(refPid) {
       $("#crRef_" + refPid).remove();

   }​
```

Answer (score 2):

Beginning an id with `#` is not valid. I believe you're confusing the id value with jQuery's CSS selectors.

`[hashTag] + [ID of Element] = CSS ID Selector`

This should work:

```
function displayCrRef(refPid, refFs, pidOfReferringP) {

    ...
    // Remove the hash tag here: id='crRef_" + refPid + "'
    $("#pwrap_" + pidOfReferringP).prepend("<div id='crRef_" + refPid + "' style='float: left;  width: 350px; margin-right: 60px; padding: 10px; background-color: #E6EDE8'>" + "<a id='crossRefRemoveButton'>Return to normal text</a>" + data + "</div>");
    ...

}

function removeCrossRef(refPid) {
    $("#crRef_" + refPid).remove();
}​
```

Additional Information

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html

Comment: Oh, my gosh what a stupid mistake. You don't know how long I have been bashing my head against the wall. However the `.attr` still doesn't seem to be working. Though i feel like i had this working earlier, even if it is not a very elegant method.

Comment: @Jeff, it happens to ***everyone***. Of course, it hasn't happened to me since the last time :)

Answer (score -3):

```
$("#crossRefRemoveButton").addEventListener('click',function(){
   removeCrossRef(rmFxnParam);
});
```

Comment: why was this given a minus 1??

Comment: Yes I'd like to know why this doesn't work. For learning purposes off course

Comment: I can give it a minus 2, if that helps...nvm I'm out of votes :D. jQuery objects don't have the method `.addEventListener`. They have the method `.on`. So that could be one reason.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't had a chance to explain my down-vote yet. This doesn't address the actual problem - the incorrect naming convention of the ID attribute. Basically, it wouldn't fix the problem

Comment: Oh! So if you would convert it to a DOM element first? or just select the DOM element? document.getElementById("crossRefRemoveButton").addEventListener(...

Comment: @MaxSnijders no don't use DOM events with jQuery at all. You are throwing cross browser support away with that.

Comment: AddEventListener is pretty damn cross-browser though.

Comment: still, inserting it within a function as I'm doing doesn't seem to go through the $(document).ready process -- thus it doesn't seem to work -- that's why I was trying to use "onClick" attribute.

Comment: This is really weird, but it seems to be that when you apply an `onClick` attribute in jquery it must be 'onClick' - the "C" must be capitalized.